# Help needed with json iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, deserialization

I m receiving data from the server. Now when i m deserializing it i m getting an `array` with key value. Now the first object of the `array` is my whole `NSDictionary` item from which i have to extract data using `keys`. I m stuck here i tried using different things like extracting them in sets but it disturbs there arrangement. I m pretty new in the field . please can anyone help me out here. How to get that array into a `NSDictionary` object or extract info using keys from that array. Thanks.

```
NSData *responseData = [[request responseString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *err = nil;
NSDictionary *dataArray = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer]deserialize:responseData error:&err];
```

it gves an array as output to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about: `NSDictionary *myDictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: how about NSDictionary *myDictionary = myArray[0]; :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) framework as a production ready library for dealing with just such issues.